# Find the surface area of the portion of the cone that is inside the cylinder

Tags: volume, multiple-integral

Find the surface area of the portion of the cone $z^2=x^2+y^2$ that is inside the cylinder $z^2=2y$.

I have seen this solution before but what bugs me is that why are we calling $z^2=2y$ as a cylinder? I tried drawing the figures on geogebra $3D$ calculator but it doesn't help me.

Comment: "cylinder" is a terminology with a far broader meaning than most mathematical neophytes are aware of. Take any curve $\gamma$ in space, and some vector $\vec u$. The set of all points that project onto $\gamma$ in the direction of $\vec u$ is called a "cylinder". That is the set $\{p \mid \exists a \in\Bbb R, p + a\vec u \in \gamma\}$. What is problematic about the question is not "cylinder", but "inside". $z^2 = 2y$ is not a closed surface, so it does not define concepts of "inside" or "outside".